# unique and sparse index causes duplicate error

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've got something like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://...');

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  token: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    sparse: true
  }
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var peter = new User();

peter.name = 'peter';
peter.token = null;

peter.save(function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log('done with peter');

  var john = new User();

  john.name = 'john';
  john.token = null;

  john.save(function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('done with john');
  });

});
```

So `peter` is created first and afterwards `john`. However when `john` is saved `mongoose` returns the following error

```
{ [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: node-login.users.$token_1  dup key: { :   null }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: node-login.users.$token_1  dup key: { : null }',
  code: 11000,
  n: 0,
  lastOp: 0,
  connectionId: 4527333,
  ok: 1 }
```

Code tried on [mongolab](https://mongolab.com) running `mongo v2.0.7` and `mongoose v3.5.1`.

I thought setting an index to `sparse` allows for multiple `null` values. Index is properly set as the "Indexes" tab in mongolab backend shows `true` for `unique` and `sparse`. Any ideas why I get the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [sparse index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes/#sparse-indexes) only indexes the field if a document *has* that field.  Whether the field is set to `null` or some other value doesn't matter, it's still checked for uniqueness if present.

So in your case, omit setting the `token` field at all instead of setting it to `null`.

Comment: I need the `token` for user registration. User signs up and email with token is sent. User clicks on link with token. My app sees the token and verifies it. After verification I would like to set the token to `null`. So in the end I will have multiple users with unique tokens and multiple with `null` tokens. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: If you want to keep the unique sparse index, don't set `token` to `null`, [`$unset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_unset) it instead to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript setting the value to null will not delete that property, rather it sets the value as null. In your case you should delete the token property.

```
delete john.token;  // In place of John.token = null
```

Do the same for peter.

Refer more on delete: [Remove a property from a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)